# How to fix 'OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket' using Tkinter, Sockets, and Threading

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\froyn\PycharmProjects\anything\client.py", line 82, in <lambda>
    self.filesendbttn = Button(self.filewin, text="Send File", font="Helvetica 10 bold", width=20, bg="#ABB2B9",command=lambda: self.sendFile())
  File "C:\Users\froyn\PycharmProjects\anything\client.py", line 86, in sendFile
    connection.send(f"{''.join(('fileId', self.filename))}".encode())
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

This error appears when I attempt to send a file over sockets. How it works is gets the files path from a tkinter entry box, converts it to bytes, appends 'fileId' to it so the receiving function can then proceed to read the remaining data. The data is routed from the client to the server, then it is broadcasted to all clients where the have a independent function there to read it.

Receiving Function:

```
    def receive(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = connection.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                if message[:6] == 'fileId':
                    message == message[6:]
                    filename = message
                    filename = os.path.basename(filename)
                    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
                        while True:
                            bytes_read = connection.recv(1024)
                            if not bytes_read:
                                break
                            f.write(bytes_read)
                            print("worked?")
```

Sending function and the function for the entering file path window

```
    def fileSendWindow(self):
        self.filewin = Toplevel(self.Window)
        self.filewin.title("File Delivery Window")
        self.filewin.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        self.filewin.configure(width=400,height=300,bg=color1)
        self.label = Label(self.filewin, text="Path of file you wish to send.\n (No quotation marks)", justify=CENTER, font="Helvetica 14 bold", bg=color1)
        self.label.place(relheight=0.15, relx=0.15, rely=0.07)
        self.fileMsg = Entry(self.filewin,bg=color3,fg="#EAECEE",font="Helvetica 13")
        self.fileMsg.place(relwidth=1,relheight=0.1,rely=0.25, relx=0.011)
        self.fileMsg.focus()
        self.filesendbttn = Button(self.filewin, text="Send File", font="Helvetica 10 bold", width=20, bg="#ABB2B9",command=lambda: self.sendFile())
        self.filesendbttn.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.36, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.30)
    def sendFile(self):
        self.filename = self.fileMsg.get()
        connection.send(f"{''.join(('fileId', self.filename))}".encode())
        with open(self.filename, "rb") as f:
            while True:
                bytes_read = f.read(1024)
                if not bytes_read:
                    break
                connection.sendall(bytes_read)
            connection.close()
```

They both belong to the same class.

Comment: What is `connection`?

Comment: should've clarified. 
connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: `sendFile()` closes the socket.  If you call it a second time, you will get an error because the socket is closed.  Is it called twice?